# Microsoft Word does not know where it saves autorecovery

Tags: microsoft-word

My computer crashed. When I open Word, and open the document I was working on, the last version saved, the autorecovery is not shown.
I go to File, History and Manage Document, "no usaved changes"..., Manage 
Document, Recover Unsaved Changes and it goes to `

> C:\Users\jgomez\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\UnsavedFiles

However, in File Options Save, the AutoRecover file location is set to

> C:\Users\jgomez\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\

There I found my work and saved my day!

I wonder how many hours of how many people are wasted due to this issue.

My question is why this is designed in this way and if you think it is a bug or misconfiguration at my end, and I hope it can help someone finding his unsaved changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have autorecover enabled and Word does not find them, it may not be looking in the right path.

You can look for autorecover .asd files in the configured location.

Go to File > Options > Save and write down the AutoRecover file location.

Browse to that folder and open the file with Word (automatically it does not know which program to use, which is also weird and funny).